# Java ScheduledFuture doesn't wait for task to finish

Tags: java

I have problem. I am using the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService tradingPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable runTradingTask = () -> {
    new TradingDriver().run();
};
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledTradingFuture = tradingPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(runTradingTask, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In my `TradingDriver.run()` I have a few SQL statements, so that takes some time, arround 1.5 seconds, but I noticed that the next run already started. To check if my thoughts were right I printed "Started" and "Ended" at the endpoints of the function. And this was my result:

```
Started
Started
Ended
Started
Ended
Started
Ended
Started
```

As you can see it prints 2x "Started", so that means another run gets started while the first one didn't finish.
Now I have seen this post: [ScheduledExecutorService wait for task to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197654/scheduledexecutorservice-wait-for-task-to-complete), but I can see that the ScheduledFuture doesn't wait for finish.

How can I run the `TradingDriver.run()` continuously with 1 second between executions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use scheduleWithFixedDelay instead of scheduleAtFixedRate

Comment: This still doesn't look like the cleanest solution. According to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29, my function should wait. I'd rather have an answer using the `ScheduledExecutor` :)